# Mobile menu (CSS and JavaScript) not opening

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following mobile menu and javascript to open/hide it on click, but it's not working - any ideas on how to fix it?

As a side note, I am not a frontend developer, I am just doing someone a favour by recreating their website on a different platform - so please go easy on me ;-)

HTML:

```
<div class="mm-trigger">
    <button class="mm-button"></button>
</div>

<nav id="mobile-menu" class="menu-top-container">
    <ul id="menu-top-1" class="mm-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-4614" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-2725 current_page_item menu-item-4614">
           <a href="" aria-current="page">Home</a>
        </li>
...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and JavaScript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Mobile Menu
        $(function () { // run after page loads
            //Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
            $(".mm-trigger").click(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(500);
                return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
            });
        });

        $(window).smartresize(function () {
            if (($(window).width() > 959)) {
                $("#mobile-menu").hide();
            }
        });
    });
}) 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I will appreciate any help in solving this, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? What is happening? What should happen?

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Comment: @cloned the mobile menu should open, but it's not opening (nothing is happening upon clicking on the hamburger)

Comment: Also why click a div when you have a button inside to click?

Comment: As noted above, I am not a developer and I just copied this from an existing website and trying to get this to work somewhere else, I didn't write any of that code..

Comment: Any errors in the console? Did you load jQuery library?

Comment: @mplungjan No errors in the console and yes, loading `jquery 1.8.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work - here is a reduced version

I changed the button to type=button and had to add some CSS to show the result of the code

The div wrapping the button is not needed and you really should click the button
If you do, you will need to remove the div or use .parent() to change the div style

```js
$(function() {
  //Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
  $(".mm-trigger").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // not really needed for type=button
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(500);
  });

/* not relevant to your question 
  $(window).smartresize(function() {
    $("#mobile-menu").toggle($(window).width() <= 959);
  });
*/

});
```

```css
.mm-trigger { width:45px }
.active { border:3px solid red }
#mobile-menu { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mm-trigger">
  <button type="button" class="mm-button">Click</button>
</div>
<nav id="mobile-menu" class="menu-top-container">
  <ul id="menu-top-1" class="mm-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4614" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-2725 current_page_item menu-item-4614">
      <a href="" aria-current="page">Home</a>
    </li>
    ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things wrong with this code but I tried to fix it as good as i could.

(function ($) { ... }) ... This doesn't do anything. 
Then inside this function you define not one, but **two** event handlers that should execute once the page is loaded. But since your initial function didn't do anything, these won't get initialized. 
You need to only define **one** handler for what should happen once the page is loaded.

You also don't need `<div class="mm-triggger"> ... </div>` wrapper around your button at all. You can bind events to buttons, that's what they are here for. So I removed the div and added the relevant class to the button.

```js
$(function() { //run after page load
  
  //Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
  $(".mm-trigger").click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```css
#mobile-menu {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="mm-button mm-trigger">Menu open</button>


<nav id="mobile-menu" class="menu-top-container">
    <ul id="menu-top-1" class="mm-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-4614" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-2725 current_page_item menu-item-4614">
           <a href="" aria-current="page">Home</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```